# Develop POS website in asp.net MVC but unable to take cut printout throught EPSON Tv88IV

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What should i do for thermal printing and receipt should be cut after each one receipt with proper format. right now i am using normal java script for printing 
so print preview is also come what should i do for stop print preview.

Thanks in advance !!